# Reading from character device with Qt

Tags: qt, file

I'm not very good at character devices, so I need your help. A have a char device(let's call it `/dev/my_light`) which is a light sensor. I have to read the data from this file and transform it to the brightness value and then pass it to the brightness manager that changes the brightness of my screen. The problem is that when I read the value for some period of time I get old values from the file.I assume there is a buffer(again not sure how character devices exactly work). Whereas when I use `cat /dev/my_light` I see new data! Is it possible to get rid off the buffer and read new values that were written to the file just right now. Here is my code in Qt:

```
    void MySensor::updateMySensor()
    {
        Packet packet;
        packet.startByte = 0;
        packet.mantissa = 0;
        packet.exp = 0;

        d->device = ::open(d->path.toStdString().c_str(), O_RDONLY);
        if (d->device == -1)
        {
            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "can't open the sensor";
            return;
        }

        ssize_t size = ::read(d->device, &packet, sizeof(packet));
        close(d->device);

        if (size == -1)
        {
            qDebug() << errno;
            return;
        }

        packet.exp &= 0x0F;

        float illumination = pow(2, packet.exp) * packet.mantissa * 0.045;

        if(d->singleShot) emit lightSensorIsRunning(true);
        emit illuminationRead(illumination);
    }
```

The `mySensor` function is called every second. I tried to call it each 200 msec but it didn't help. The value of illumination stays old for about 7 seconds(!) whereas the value that I get from `cat` is new just immediately.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: We are not sure about specifics of that device to be confident with the answer. Of course if there was no update on device you may get the same value from it. How do we know that new data is available? From my past experience some devices singal about new data and we can watch on them with either POSIX select or epoll. Looks like somewhat related article: https://jvns.ca/blog/2017/06/03/async-io-on-linux--select--poll--and-epoll/

Comment: @AlexanderV thanxs for your answer! The problem is that with `cat` I can see new values just right now. And inside my program I see them after 7 seconds as I said above. I cannot understand why. Maybe I was not very clear in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test with your specific device, however, I'm using the keyboard as a read only device.

The program attempts to connect to keyboard and read all keys pressed inside and outside the window. It's a broad solution you'll have to adapt to meet your demands.

Note that I'm opening the file with `O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK` which means open in read only mode and no wait for the event be triggered(some notifier needed to know when data is ready!) respectively.

You'll need super user privilege to run this example!

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/input.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    const char *device_name = "/dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd";

    int descriptor = open(device_name, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);

    if (descriptor < 0)
    {
        qDebug() << "Error" << strerror(errno);
        return a.exec();
    }

    QFile device;

    if (!device.open(descriptor, QFile::ReadOnly))
    {
        qDebug() << "Error" << qPrintable(device.errorString());
        return a.exec();
    }

    QSocketNotifier notifier(device.handle(), QSocketNotifier::Read);

    QObject::connect(&notifier, &QSocketNotifier::activated, &notifier, [&](int socket){
        Q_UNUSED(socket)

        struct input_event ev;

        QByteArray data = device.readAll();

        qDebug() << "Event caught:"
                 << "\n\nDATA SIZE" << data.size()
                 << "\nSTRUCT COUNT" << data.size() / int(sizeof(input_event))
                 << "\nSTRUCT SIZE" << sizeof(input_event);

        qDebug() << ""; //New line

        while (data.size() >= int(sizeof(input_event)))
        {
            memcpy(&ev, data.data(), sizeof(input_event));

            data.remove(0, int(sizeof(input_event)));

            qDebug() << "TYPE" << ev.type << "CODE" << ev.code << "VALUE" << ev.value << "TIME" << ev.time.tv_sec;
        }

        qDebug() << ""; //New line
    });

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you! But why is it necessary to use both  `O_NONBLOCK`  `O_NDELAY`? They are the same...Or am I wrong?

Comment: QSocketNotifier is that thing that uses underlying select or epoll.

Comment: @PolinaBodnar: you are right, `O_NDELAY` is an obsolete name for `O_NONBLOCK` and shouldn't be used in new applications. I'll remove it from the answer!